# java-Hazelcast configurable transport layer

Tags: java, networking, udp, hazelcast, distributed-system

I'm using Hazelcast cluster manager on my distributed Java application and I want to configure Hazelcast to use UDP, specifically for the event bus. My understanding is that Hazelcast will create point-to-point TCP connections while using the event bus. Is there any way to configure Hazelcast to use UDP and multicast events across the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

UDP is the default discovery mechanism for Hazelcast, TCP needs to be explicitly enabled. See documentation for setting up Hazelcast discovery: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-up-clusters

Comment: I'm familiar with multicast discovery. I'm asking specifically about the event bus or any other inter-node communication mechanism (anything except socket programming)

Comment: You can use non-TCP discovery for servers to detect each other and form a cluster. Everything after that is on TCP and that’s not optional.